# Weird flickering in my model when I rotate the camera and even if it's fixed

Tags: modeling, objects

I was working on this model and everything was going fine. After I finished making the hands I took a look at the full model and noticed this weird flickering. Naturally I tried merging by distance and recalculating the normals, but nothing changed, the flickering continued when I switched render engines.

I tried re-opening Blender and restarting my computer but the problem continued.
Here's video: [Weird flickering in Blender 2.83](https://youtu.be/hw3L4qRaF-g)

What troubles me the most is that it wasn't happening earlier today, I clearly made a mistake or pushed a wrong button in the process of modeling, but I have no idea what exactly.

EDIT: [Google-Drive Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wbmsrPxNkArwlKZ5873tFWpE4WuNtxGM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. for me it worked out to make a new file and then appending the object from your .blend file into it. No flickering anymore. Reason, sadly not sure, but it looked like z-fighting.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes from floating point rounding error due to the clip start / end of your camera view. Basically you have somehow set the camera view to have a culling range that is too wide (from 0.0001 m to 1000 m) so the viewport rendering is flickering when you zoom out.

To fix it, set the clip start to a higher value (0.01 m should be good). Go to the right side panel with <kbd>N</kbd> and inside the "View" panel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because your mirror modifier is copying and mirroring each side independently without culling one side. Check you mirror modifier options and check bisect then check or un-check flip to choose which side to delete and which side to mirror.

[image]

Probably what you did was apply the mirror modifier at some point.

Comment: That's not it, I even deleted the mirror modifier without applying it but the problem continued. I edited the question with a link to the blend file.